# Why is IOS 7.0.3 picker goofing up my LiveCode webform?

Tags: iphone, ios7, livecode, drupal-webform

I don't know where the best place to ask about this is. My problem seems to be with IOS 7.0.3 and how Safari is handling the picker in a web form. I've created a web form with LiveCode that works just fine in every browser I've tried. But on the iPhone, the picker malfunctions. If you choose one item and press Done, it reverts to 0 items chosen. If you choose two items and press done, it shows one item chosen. The same goes for three, four, and so on. Has anyone else had this experience? Here is a snippet of one of the multiple choice buttons.

```
<label for="authors[]">
Select Author(s)
  <select name="authors[]" id="authors" multiple="yes" size="7" >
<?lc
    put the number of lines in tAuthorList into tTotalAuthors
    repeat with x = 1 to tTotalAuthors
        put "<option value=" & q(line x of tAuthorList)
        put lineOffset(line x of tAuthorList,tPrevAuthors) into tLineHit
        if bDataSubmitted and line x of tAuthorList is line tLineHit of tPrevAuthors then
            put " selected"
        end if
        put ">" & line x of tAuthorList & "</option>" & return
    end repeat
?>      
  </select>
</label>
```

This is the URL:
http://lc.scs.earlham.edu/soul_therapy3.lc

Incidentally, I use it with an iframe in my Drupal 7 site:

http://soulshare.org/soul_therapy/tool

Comment: I created a web form in Drupal with a multiple choice listbox and tested it in IOS 7.0.3 and it is not working right. I get the same result as I do with my LiveCode webform. So it's not LiveCode that's the problem. I don't understand why I don't see anyone pointing out this problem. I'll have to submit it to Apple and see what they say.

Comment: The multi-select issue occurs in iOS 7.0.3 in both Safari and Chrome (which is stuck using the same WebKit afaik). I have reproduced the issue with a minimal HTML page where the select wheel has very puzzling behaviour. https://gist.github.com/nathany/7328609 I've submitted the HTML example as an issue to Apple on October 29th, 2013. No response so far. Feel free to open an issue as well, it will help Apple recognize that multiple people are experiencing it: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue (design choice?) in iOS7 where you need to not only scroll to the correct value but also tap your selected value. I don't know if this is your problem though...

In some forms you only needs to scroll to the correct value but in many, you need to scroll and THEN select. As you probably have guessed this has nothing to do with LiveCode...

Comment: Right. I tried the demo website and everything works normally, perhaps because I tapped after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IOS and has been reported to apple. Currently the best solution I've found uses jQuery to fix the selected items upon closing the picker. Simply paste this into your JS file and away you go.

```
// hack for iPhone 7.0.3 multiselects bug
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    $('select[multiple]').each(function(){
        var select = $(this).on({
            "focusout": function(){
                var values = select.val() || [];
                setTimeout(function(){
                    select.val(values.length ? values : ['']).change();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        var firstOption = '<option value="" disabled="disabled"';
        firstOption += (select.val() || []).length > 0 ? '' : ' selected="selected"';
        firstOption += '>&laquo; Select ' + (select.attr('title') || 'Options') + ' &raquo;';
        firstOption += '</option>';
        select.prepend(firstOption);
    });
}
```

[Multiple select in Safari iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039194/multiple-select-in-safari-ios-7?answertab=votes#tab-top)