# MVC 3.5/Razor: Listbox + Option 'Selected' Value is being Ignored

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, select, razor

I'm ready to smack my head into a wall with this one.  I'm working on a mobile site using JQuery, ASP.Net 3.5/C#/Razor, and I'm trying to allow a user to select a group of Affiliations that they belong to, in a listbox.

```
<select id="Affiliations" name="Affiliations" multiple="multiple" size="5"  autocomplete="off">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="2334">2 Rivers Racing</option>
<option value="2366">Adventure 212</option>
<option value="2328">Baraboo Sharks</option>
<option value="2352">BELGIANWERKX</option>
...
</select>
```

This works out well. The user can select as many as they want, and save the form.  The page reloads, and the items that they selected 'appear' to be selected in the listbox.  I say 'appear' because the big button that you click to bring up the iOS selector has the option text visible, but they're not checked off at all.

```
<select id="Affiliations" name="Affiliations" multiple="multiple" size="5"  autocomplete="off">
<option value="0"></option>
<option selected="selected" value="2334">2 Rivers Racing</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2366">Adventure 212</option>
<option value="2328">Baraboo Sharks</option>
<option value="2352">BELGIANWERKX</option>
...
</select>
```

If I hit save on the form, it clears out the form values like nothing was selected even though the HTML suggests otherwise.  The only time data gets passed from the view -> controller is when the person clicks and selects an item themselves.

What would be causing a problem such as this?  Or hell, how do I fix something like this? I attached a photo describing what happens.  I would assume that if the values were no longer selected, they wouldn't appear anymore as the text in the selectbox (middle picture)?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039194/multiple-select-in-safari-ios-7

Comment: Firefox (when using an iphone browser user agent) does the same thing. I'll test with older iPhones and iPads to see if it's a safari/mobile issue or if it's something with my code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I couldn't see anything wrong with your code. Hopefully you come right :)