# iOS 8 multiple <select> serious bug on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, ios8, html-select

In iOS 8.0, Apple introduced a new bug in Safari on iPhone, which I think is very serious when using multiple `<select>` elements. It's commonly used for example to select day of birth. To reproduce:

1. Create a page with two `<select>` with multiple `<option>` in each
2. Open in Safari on iOS 8 on iPhone (The bug still exists in 8.0.2)
3. Tap the first `<select>`
4. Choose the third option i.e. March
5. Notice that it doesn't update the `<select>` to what you chose (it does in iOS 7)
6. Tap the second `<select>` element
7. Notice the following:

   - The first `<select>` doesn't update
   - The second `<select>` shows 3 (which is the position of the first `<select>`)
   - The picker below shows 1

You can repeat this by alternating between tapping the first and second `<select>`, and notice that it changes in the same pattern. This may appear randomly unless you know the pattern). It looks even more confusing if you also have a year-picker.

To try in your mobile device, try this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m7baw590/6/embedded/result/

Also, the `onchange="alert(this.value)"` reports an incorrect value (the same that is selected on the second `<select>` element. You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/m7baw590/7/embedded/result/

These bugs does not occur if you click "Done" between each selection, or use the arrows to switch.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I submitted this bug report to apple as issue 18701881, and got a reply that it was a duplicate of 18484444. According to the number it seems to be a while ago. If anyone has a workaround until they fix it, I'd like to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039194/multiple-select-in-safari-ios-7

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 9.

Comment: I had the same issue. Problem was my select fields were wrapped in a <label> tag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408079

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    (...)
    <optgroup disabled></optgroup>
</select>
```

Just added an empty `<optgroup>` to the `<select>`.

Comment: Impressive! This worked! It seems like a weird hack though. Here's a fiddle that works in iPhone :) http://jsfiddle.net/m7baw590/12/embedded/result/

Comment: this works, but now the interface to choose options looks kind of different, aligned to the left rather than centered.

Comment: The control does not load now

Comment: Does anybody know something about a bugreport on iOS. Because I still have this weird behaviour on iOS 10.2 and 10.3

Comment: Still present in 10.4.4, the workaround does work 
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        $('select').each(function () {
            $(this).append("<optgroup disabled></optgroup>");
        });

Answer (score 10):

I discovered another bug with select fields in iOS8 (Only on iPhone, iPad seems fine for example).

http://jsbin.com/kuhogopafe/1

How to reproduce:

- Select 3 options
- Unselect one option again
- Result: instead of 2
  selected options, only the last unselected option is reported as
  selected now

Comment: I can confirm the bug. I would guess it's due to similar buggy code from Apple. Hope they fix it soon.

Comment: I am experiencing the same bug with iOS 8.1.1 on iPhone 5

Comment: Running into the same issue on iOS 8.1.3 on iPhone 5.

Comment: This is still valid with iOS 9.2 on iPhone 6s

Comment: Just encountered this bug with multiselects on iOS 9.2 on iPhone 6+. Given it's happened on iOS 7 and 8 and now 9, it's apparent that Apple doesn't do regression testing. "It Just Works" my a\*\*.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found for iphone Safari is to disable all other select boxes onfocus and re-enable all onblur. This will force the user to push Done.