# iOS Safari Selecting Dropdown

Tags: ios, angular, twitter-bootstrap, safari, dropdown

[image]

Hi there. Some of my users who are using Safari on iOS have problems selecting the second dropdown field (In this case the "Month" dropdown).

The way to do it, is actually to use the left and right arrows (See screenshot), but several of my userbase for some reason don't know that.

I'm using Bootstrap.

Is there a way how to browser-side deactivate the standard iOS dropdown interface, so that they can freely select the dropdown fields without having to use the "left and right arrows"?

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the three dropdown fields were surrounded by a label html tag. In Chrome and Firefox this isn't a problem, but on Safari, clicking on one dropdown will always set the focus back on the first drop down field.

Once I had converted the label html tag to a div html tag, the problem was solved, and the dropdown fields could be individually selected again.