# Select Multiple for iOS 7

Tags: ios, html

There is a known issue with iOS 7 and Select Multiples. I've seen it referenced on here before (  [Multiple select in Safari iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039194/multiple-select-in-safari-ios-7) ) but have yet to find a solution to it.

Does anyone know a work around to get select multiple to work with iOS7? Or how to disabled the spinner?

Example: I choose 3 items from select multiple. When I hit done, only 2 items are there. If I choose 1 item, it will zero out when hitting done. Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple select in Safari iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039194/multiple-select-in-safari-ios-7)