# Prevent auto select first option of multiselect box in iPhone Safari

Tags: html, ios

I have a problem with multiselect box on iPhone Safari. When I open the multiselect box it automatically selects the first option. Here is the code snippet that i am using:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

I have added a blank option with the `disabled` attribute (see below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660500/mobile-safari-multi-select-bug)) as the first option but it didn't work in iPhone Safari. I am using an iPhone 6s+:

```
    <option disabled></option>
```

Comment: The real issue is that when iOS selects the first option, it doesn't bind it to the object in the backend (Angular 8). One of the answers below is actually the best one. You should add a blank/suggestive option at the top of the options stack. I am still looking for an address form I can open up in iOS and Windows Chrome that doesn't use Autocomplete or Geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

```
disable=disable
```

just add it in option so that no one will be able to access that option

Answer (score -1):

```
<option selected=selected value="test0">Pick an option</option>
```

Use the attribute `selected` to specify that this option should be the one selected. Or put the first one you want to see selected by default at the top of your list.

`disabled` attribute will, well i know how unprobable it sounds, disable your select option, thus means it will not be able to be selected.

Comment: is there any option instead of add "Pick an option" line to the select box

Comment: selected is enough. Not selected=selected, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: @PrinceGautam yup, replace it with any value you want to be shown. Pick an option is simply a default place holder that'll tell the user that he has to pick an option.

Comment: @Alexis  In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the selected attribute must be defined as <option selected="selected">. You're free to use bad practices in your HTML, therefore you shouldnt encourage it :) ( see a little bit below your own link )

Comment: Don't think we speak about xhtml in question. :o

Comment: Today's market consists of different browser technologies. Some browsers run on computers, and some browsers run on mobile phones or other small devices. Smaller devices often lack the resources or power to interpret "bad" markup.

XML is a markup language where documents must be marked up correctly (be "well-formed").

Y'all should speak about xhtml when doing web.

Comment: but if i add "Pick an option" as selected then display a tick on it in mobile that is not looking great. Please suggest if any other option to solve this or "Pick an option" should not be click-able on mobile

Comment: @JorelAmthor yeah but OP marked the question as `html` and not `xhtml`.

Comment: add selected="selected" on another value you want to be selected by default then, or you validation to prevent people from selecting "Pick an option"

Comment: @Chris So what ? Do you know the difference between XHTML and HTML ? If you guys want to win an argument, you gotta come with better examples than those. selected="selected" is a better practice than selected, because it helps other device to intepret HTML, helps your browser to interpret HTML. And it's still valid HTML. No downside to this. Dont be so rigid in your bad habits.

Comment: wow, you're quite volatile aren't you? No, there's no downside to using the xhtml version, and it's good that you added that you pointed this out. But you went off-topic there for a second and tried convincing others to use what you deem as correct. The question is not about xhtml vs html, and your comment was off-topic and that's what I pointed that out. I also don't know what "argument" you were referring to??

Comment: @Chris How off topic am i vs how off topic are you ? except trolling, what are you and Alexis doing ? I tried to convice people to use what is blatantely correct, not what i deem as correct, and you trolls come to brought me off topics because of your very short sight and narrow mind. " OP said it was html and not XHTML " is pure troll.

Comment: @JorelAmthor yes, i want to prevent people from selecting "Pick an option"

Comment: Any news ? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: This is the answer closest to providing a unified experience across browsers. But what do I know, UX people can't seem to agree on anything to make things easier for us developers.